# IsCmdBuild.exe building compressed msi but failing to open

Tags: installation, installshield, setup-project, installshield-2015

I am trying to build installer using InstallShield's commandline tool IsCmdBld.exe. It builds something, but when I try to open it, it returns following error.

[image: Failing to open]

I have used

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2015\System\IsCmdBld.exe" -p "D:\Installation_Builds\MyInstallations\MyInstaller.ism" -r "Compressed EN Build" -c COMP  -a "CompEN"`

as a command. Seems very straight forward. In fact if I do not insert `-c COMP` and generate uncompressed installer, it has no problem. However, the size of installer over all becomes 23GB so it is not acceptable.

I do see `ISDEV : fatal error 0:` followed by nothing else. I googled a bit and found http://flexerasoftware.force.com/ka1G0000000TljoIAC but I cannot seem to understand why this is occuring when I can perfectly build it without the use of commandline tool.

Any inputs would be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT : after adding `-v` to the building command, little bit more detailed error showed up.

1627: Error saving the changes to [XX.msi]

I do not know why it is erroring on saving the change.

Comment: Fatal Error 0 indicates an unexpected exception must have been thrown. Adding `-v` to your iscmdbld command line can sometimes help identify where it is when this happens. That can in turn result in an idea of what to look for.

Comment: @MichaelUrman Hi Michael, thanks to you it had little bit more details. 1627: Error saving the changes to [XX.msi] I will search what this means and why it is failing to copy.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your .msi is not readonly.

the best way we found for using the isCmdBld is with this cmdline :

```
ISCmdBld.exe -p "%ProjectName%" -a "%Configuration%" -r "%ReleaseName%" -x -o "%MergeModulePath%" -prqpath "%PRQPath%"
```

you'll have to make sure the %Configuration% and %ReleaseName% are the exact same as those in the ism (case Sensitive) (Media|release).